# LINQ Query to join 2 different tables

Tags: c#, html, linq, razor

I am currently working on library management project, which users update their reading status when they borrow a book. When I use linq to join tables, everything else except status is there.
Here are my models:
User model(TblUser):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LibMan.Models.DB
{
    public partial class TblBookStatus
    {
        public int ResId { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int? BookId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public virtual TblBook Book { get; set; }
        public virtual TblUser User { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Book Model(TblBook):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LibMan.Models.DB
{
    public partial class TblBook
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Translator { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public byte[] Cover { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Book Status Model(TblBookStatus):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LibMan.Models.DB
{
    public partial class TblBookStatus
    {
        public int ResId { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int? BookId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public virtual TblBook Book { get; set; }
        public virtual TblUser User { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And moving on to my code below, you can see I created DisplayBook with linq query join, but I can't display status in html side. It says it

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LibMan.Models.DB;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

namespace LibMan.Pages
{
    public class LibraryModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly LibMan.Models.DB.LibManContext _context;
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public LibraryModel(LibMan.Models.DB.LibManContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            DisplayBook = new List<TblBook>();
;       }
        public IList<TblBookStatus> TblBookStatus { get; set; }
        public IList<TblBook> TblBook { get; set; }
        public IList<TblBook> DisplayBook { get; set; }
        public IList<TblUser> TblUser{ get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            TblBookStatus = await _context.TblBookStatus.ToListAsync();
            TblBook = await _context.TblBook.ToListAsync();
            TblUser = await _context.TblUser.ToListAsync();
            var UserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email");

            if (TblBookStatus != null && TblBook != null)
            {
                DisplayBook = (from book in TblBook
                                join stat in TblBookStatus
                                on book.BookId equals stat.BookId
                                join usr in TblUser
                                on stat.UserEmail equals usr.Email
                                where (usr.Email == UserEmail)
                                select book).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this? Can I do this inside the statement that DisplayBook is assigned to the Linq query result? What is the best way to do this? Thanks!
Note: I can provide html code if needed.

Comment: `TblBookStatus` has nullable `BookId`, why is so? Because it looks like this table is just many-to-many between books and users. It would make more sense to move `public string Status { get; set; }` to separate table and `TblBookStatus` have reference to it.

Comment: And what are you trying to show with `DisplayBook`?

Comment: BookId on TblBookStatus is managed as a foreign key on the database, thats why it is nullable, it is automatically generated when I set up the project. On the displaybook statement, when a user adds a book to their library, I display it on that page, I display the book information. Also I want to display Status from TblBookStatus, which is not in DisplayBook. One user with one book. As you said, this project is for many users and books.

Comment: One user can have only one book?

Comment: Can you please add your `User` class, you have `TblBookStatus` repeated twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options. You can correct your code changing type of `DisplayBook` to valuetuple (or create separate type for readability) :

```
 public IList<(TblBook Book, TblBookStatus  Status)> DisplayBook { get; set; }
```

Fetch books and statuses with users:

```
TblBookStatus = await _context.TblBookStatus.Include(s => s.User).ToListAsync();
TblBook = await _context.TblBook.ToListAsync();
```

And lastly fill the `DisplayBook`:

```
DisplayBook = TblBook
    .Select(b => (b, TblBookStatus.FirstOrDefault(s => s.BookId == b.BookId)))
    .ToList()
```

As far as I understand from your comments you have one-to-one relation between status and user, so this way you will have all books in your library fetched and all statuses(status for book can be `null`) with filled user relation.

P.S.

`ToListAsync` should not return null, so null checks are redundant there.

**UPD**

To fetch info only about one user and his books you can do it with single query:

```
var statusesWithUserAndBooks = await _context.TblBookStatus
    .Include(s => s.User)
    .Include(s => s.Book)
    .Where(s => s.User.Email == UserEmail)
    .ToListAsync();
```

If you need a subset of data, then create [`DTO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) with necessary fields, like this:

```
public class DisplayBookDTO
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string BookAuthor { get; set; }
}

public IList<DisplayBookDTO> DisplayBook { get; set; }

DisplayBook = await _context.TblBookStatus
    .Where(s => s.User.Email == UserEmail
        && s.Book != null)
    .Select(s => new DisplayBookDTO
    {
        Status = s.Status,
        BookTitle = s.Book.Title,
        BookAuthor = s.Book.Author
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and I can finally see status as an output, but when DisplayBook is displayed, all books on the database(every book on TblBook) got displayed. Trying to fix this now. Any ideas?

Comment: The Library page contains users own library, which they added books from TblBook. Since a user can have more than one book and they are more than one user, status must be displayed for a user and a book that which user reserved it, not all the books and statuses should be displayed.

Comment: @Fuzzyy was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

No need to query each table separately, and then join.  Let LINQ do it for you.

```
var UserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email");

var books = _context.TblBookStatus
     .Where(
        tbs => (tbs.Book != null && tbs.BookId == tbs.Book.BookId) &&
               (tbs.User != null && tbs.UserEmail == tbs.User.Email) &&
               tbs.UserEmail == UserEmail)
     .Select(tbs => tbs.Book);
```

Because you have navigation properties defined in the EF models (using virtual properties), the joins will automatically be done for you.  In the above example, I am setting tbs.BookId == tbs.Book.BookId.  This does not need to be done if you have foreign key defined in entity type configurations.  You can alternatively define these relationships using attributes in your EF models.

Example:

```
[ForeignKey("BookId")]
public virtual TblBook Book { get; set; }
```

EDIT: Break down what you need to return:

```
var books = _context.TblBookStatus
         .Where(
            tbs => (tbs.Book != null && tbs.BookId == tbs.Book.BookId) &&
                   (tbs.User != null && tbs.UserEmail == tbs.User.Email) &&
                   tbs.UserEmail == UserEmail)
         .Select(tbs => new {
                   Status = tbs.Status,
                   BookName = tbs.Book.Name
                             });
```

Comment: Oh , I didn't know that. So how can I display var books, I previously had a list DisplayBook which was used to display on html.

Comment: You can add .ToList() at the end to still make it a list. Select(tbs => tbs.Book).ToList();

Comment: I still cannot display the sttaus from TblBookStatus, I know DisplayBook is a type of TblBook, but when i try to print it on html side in a table, I can't. I can provide you with html code.

Comment: View my edit above.  If you added the navigation properties (virtual properties I mentioned in original answer), you can flatten the return result.  Place a breakpoint after you make this change and see if you get the desired results before it returns to client-side (html).  If you would like, create a new StackOverflow question and post your client-side code there.  We can then concentrate on that piece.

Comment: Also, want to mention that if you do not use the navigation property in the WHERE clause or SELECT, the join does not take place at all. It is best to explicitly define all the properties you want to return in the select.